# onclick on a jquery tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, onclick

I have 3 tabs, on the last one I have a form with submit button.
When the user click on submit, I would like to display a dialog box.
The problem:
it display a box(without my text) for 2seconds, and the page is refreshing and goes on the first tab, so we can't see the dialog.
Do you have any idea of the problem?

Here a little sample of the code:

```
 if (isset($_POST['Send'])) 
{ 
code to add in db
}

<script>
function thanks_referral() {
simpleModal("/thanks_referral.php",300,130);
    }
</script>

 <form method="post" onsubmit="return checkEmailContact(document.f.emailreferral.value);">
<input type="text" tabindex="1" name="name2" placeholder="friend's name" />
    <input type="email" tabindex="2" name="email2" placeholder="friend's company email" />
    <input type="submit" tabindex="4" name = "Send" onclick="" value="Send"  /></td></tr>
        </form>
```

Comment: I don't see where your code actually calls `thanks_referral()`

Comment: it's another file saying just "thank you, ....), it works for other page. I found a way, I display my popup after refreshing the page, but I would prefer to stay on my 3rd tab!

Answer (score 0):

Use [.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) on your form and do your dialog event on the callback.